# Equality of variance - three or more related samples

Tags: variance, coefficient-of-variation

I wondered if anyone could help with the following issue…

Rather than just assessing whether there is a difference between two means (considering the variance of each sample), I would like to be able to assess the difference between multiple samples’ variances, or coeeficients of variation (i.e. answering the question ‘does one condition vary more than another?’). I would like to actually compare the variance/coefficient of variation between 4 different stockings, for the pressure they apply in a single/constant group of 15 individuals (4 x repeated measures). This is to assess whether different brands (including a custom fitted stocking) have a larger or smaller "spread" of applied pressures.

For two related samples I could use the Sokal (1980) test (https://academic.oup.com/sysbio/article/29/1/50/1655230). However, this test doesn’t work for 3 or more conditions. In the final paragraph of the Sokal paper, the authors suggest using “Levene's test… applied to logarithmically transformed variables, using a randomized complete blocks design”. Another more recent paper (citing Sokal) did this recently: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/336597568_A_Novel_Method_for_Assessing_Enamel_Thickness_Distribution_in_the_Anterior_Dentition_as_a_Signal_for_Gouging_and_Other_Extractive_Foraging_Behaviors_in_Gummivorous_Mammals

However, I was under the impression that Levene’s test assumed independent samples?  ([https://www.spss-tutorials.com/levenes-test-in-spss/#:~:text=Levene's%20test%20basically%20requires%20two,is%2C%20not%20nominal%20or%20ordinal](https://www.spss-tutorials.com/levenes-test-in-spss/#:%7E:text=Levene%27s%20test%20basically%20requires%20two,is%2C%20not%20nominal%20or%20ordinal)), and I would like to do this with related observations!

Finally, the Feltz and Miller (1996) test also compares CVs between independent groups (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/cvequality/vignettes/how_to_test_CVs.html). However... again, this test seems to have been used with related samples, with the example in the associated R package being used to analysed difference in artifact length versus breadth or width... even though each measure is taken for a single artifact (repeated/related measures).

- Is this because, as we're not comparing multiple measures of the same factor (e.g. test-retest; Length 1, Length 2  --> difference --> CV etc.) there's an argument to treat these as independent measurements?

If you have any thoughts or suggestions, I’d be really grateful for any advice.